# Floating navigation bar ONLY works with UTF-8 charset

Tags: css, utf-8

I have a website with a floating navigation bar which works perfectly when the charset is set at UTF-8, but if I change it to Windows-1252 or iso-8859-1, it doesn't display.Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Without any details about which navigation bar you speak and without any code where this bar appears, and the code where you set the character set, this question will remain just that: a lonesome question.

Comment: why don't you use UTF-8 ?.

Comment: @trincot, I never thought the charset of a page would influence the css display, that's why I didnt post any code,how can the charset influence the way the styling rules are displayed?

Comment: @Elec I need to run a contact form which I cannot edit and the text from this form is in Portuguese, utf-8 doesn't reproduce the special characters properly.